# Python 3.8.6 Invalid Character in identifier splittext

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a script in Python 3.8.6 to load .sql files into big query. We're adding some non .sql files into our repo and I want my python script to only look at sql files, so I added an if statement in my loop and now I get an error: Invalid Character in identifier.

```
for filename in os.listdir(self.script_dir):
    if os.path.splitext(filename)[1] == '.sql':
        self.logger.info(os.path.join(self.script_dir, filename))
        sql = self.read_sql(os.path.join(self.script_dir, filename))
```

Any idea as to why this is happening? There is actually only one file in the directory that its running for, which does not have a .sql extension. The original file was a text file saved with no extension (we use it to check in empty folders), I added a .txt extension to it as well and still get the same error.

Comment: paste the error and the full stacktrace, we can't see your screen :)

Comment: Sorry. Here's what it shows: 
  File "c:\xxxx\Database\BigQuery\executesqlfiles.py", line 62
    if os.path.splitext(filename)[1] == '.sql':
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there is a [zero width space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) somewhere, copied from some website or pdf. Try to delete the line and retype it.

Comment: Thanks. This was the problem. I copied it from a chat box, my manager wanted me to add that line. Notepad++ didn't show any weird characters but manually retyping fixed it all